# How to view my promoted tweets in the Twitter app to debug JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, marketing, twitter, ppc

I'm driving traffic to a website with PPC on Twitter. AWS CloudWatch is reporting that 80% of my visitors are experiencing JavaScript errors — but 100% of those errors are happening in the on-device/in-app browser (i.e., when Twitter opens a website in the app, rather than kicking you out to Chrome or Safari or whatnot).

I need to debug this, but I can't find a way to actually see the promoted tweets themselves from within the twitter app. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Would you get the same behaviour (i.e. the page running in the Twitter app's browser) if you just click a link to a site from a standard tweet? If so, you can just tweet a link to the site (probably from a private account or similar) and then just click the link that way. You may need to remove/reset the default behaviour of links on your device to test this, on my Android clicking promoted links or normal links just opens my browser.